# Error running Android Studio - "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem running Android Studio 3.1.0

Error message:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
Searched in the following locations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gradle wrapper is what you're looking for. You can change the wrapper's settings in your project's gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Change

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2
```

instead of

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1
```